# localStorage Angular 4 not accessible

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm building a website using angular 4 and `nodejs`. When I try to log in, `node` sends the data, to angular, which works fine. Its just that when I attempt the login, data doesn't gets stored in local storage.

Here is the code of `auth.services.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired }  from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


//import { User } from '../../User';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    authToken: any;
    user: any;

    constructor(private http:Http, private router: Router) {
      console.log("authorization service initialized...");
    }

    signIn(user) {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', JSON.stringify(user), {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json());
    }

    storeUserData(token, user) {
      console.log("storeuserdata");
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.authToken = token;
      this.user = user;
    }

    logout() {
      this.authToken = null;
      this.user = null;
      localStorage.clear();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    }

    getProfile() {
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.loadToken();
      headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
      headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json());
    }

    loadToken() {
      this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    }

    loggedIn() {
      return tokenNotExpired();
    }
}
```

Here is the navbar.component.ts since it contains the login part

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
//import { User } from '../../../User';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: `./navbar.component.html`,
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit{
  signInForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  OnSignIn() {
      const user = {
        email: this.signInForm.value.email,
        password: this.signInForm.value.password
      };
      this.authService.signIn(user)
          .subscribe(
              data => {
                  console.log(data);
                  if (data.success) {
                    this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('profile');
                  } else {

                  }
              },
              error => console.log(error)
          );
      this.signInForm.reset();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.signInForm = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl(null, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
        ]),
        password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      });
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}
```

This is what I receive when I attempt login

```
Object {success: true, token: "JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyIkX18iO…Tc0fQ.rte25znZW9oASt-6scViAbA37W1DzXxCcg0Z_CMKWTY", user: Object}
```

and I also get success from the node js part.

When I build this website I was using angular 2. I got busy with my classes and didn't have time to finish it and angular 4 was released. I copied all the code to a fresh directory and made sure that all the node modules are build from start.

Here is my package.json that i had before:

```
{
  "name": "angular-src",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.20",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-uploader": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "^2.2.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

and this is the new package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-src",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-uploader": "^3.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

When I run the app with old version of node_modules, it works finne but when I use the new version, user never logs in.

Comment: you can try using this packaage this may help if you are not using this 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage

Comment: How do you know it's not stored in localStorage?

Comment: I will try to use that rahul.
When i try to log in, i check local storage in chrome developer tools, its not there but when i stop the server and run the project that uses the old angular version, the user gets logged in automatically and it appears in the localstorage. That's why i think its just not accessing local storage for some reason

Comment: When clicking on "Local Storage" in inspector, do you see anything at all or is it just the arrow changing direction? Can you at least your URL bellow "Local Storage"?

Comment: The only thing i see is the arrow changing direction. No url in local storage

Comment: I tried the angular-2-local-storage as well, its not working either

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong here. Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the line `localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);` and hovering over the values?

Comment: I figured it out. Something is wrong with the version of angular2-jwt. I changed the version to 0.2.0 and it works fine.